# advanced filter to remove params from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I wonder if someone can help a google analytics novice out?

Basically I have SEO friendly URL's like /search/findprices/x/12/b/121/c/12121

Where everything after the /search/findprices/ are extra params - I wish to see the number of /search/findprices/ there are regardless of the params? could anyone explain how I would use the google analytics filters to achieve this?

Also is it possible to setup secondary filters which I can also report on, for example say independently from above I want to track the number of x=12 (/x/12)?

Does that make sense?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To see all views to `/search/findprices/...` aggregated together

   - go to `Content>Content Drilldown` on the left nav.
2. To see all of the views for x=12

   - Go to `Content>Top Content`.
   - In the filter at the bottom type. `/search/findprices.*/x/12/`